# get List of counts from table based on dates in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to fetch List of counts from table by `department` here is my table structure

```
empid  empname  department   departmentId   joinedon
```

i want to populate all the joined employee on `today` , `yesterday` and `More than 2 days` like `[12,25,89]`  i.e

```
          12*    joined today
          25    joined yesterday
          81    joined all prior to yesterday(2+day)
```

`*` 0 if there isn't any entries for given date range.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the data department wise?

Comment: @Popeye yes i want `data department wise`

Answer (score 0):

You would use aggregation on a `case` expression:

```
select (case when joinedon::date = current_date then 'today'
             when joinedon::date = current_date - interval '1 day' then 'yesterday'
             when joinedon::date < current_date - interval '1 day' then 'older'
       end) as grp,
      count(*)
from t
group by grp;
```

Comment: How do add default `0` if there isn't any record lets say on `today` as `0`

Comment: tried `coalesce(count(*),0)` but its not working

Comment: That is not the question you asked here.  Incidentally, `count()` never returns `NULL`, so `coalesce()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to @Gordon Linoff answer:

```
SELECT 
    days.day,
    coalesce(t.cnt, 0) count
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('today'), ('yesterday'), ('older')) AS days (day)
)days
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT (CASE WHEN joinedon::date = current_date THEN 'today'
               WHEN joinedon::date = current_date - interval '1 day' THEN 'yesterday'
               WHEN joinedon::date < current_date - interval '1 day' THEN 'older'
         end) as day,
        count(*) cnt
  FROM t
  GROUP BY day
) t on t.day = days.day;
```

Test it [here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d763c8ab918fce5abe0d86eaec4a9706&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` as follows:

```
select department,
       (case when joinedon::date = current_date then 'today'
             when joinedon::date = current_date - interval '1 day' then 'yesterday'
             when joinedon::date < current_date - interval '1 day' then 'More than 2 days'
       end) as grp,
      Coalesce(count(*),0)
from t
group by grp, department;
```